# Setting a second price label for WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In WooCommerce I have a single product view with one price displayed. I want to add another price tag, which should show the original price divided by a number.

Right Now I am working in the **`cart.php`** file which is in my themes folder and that is my code:

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> / Flasche <br> </p>
<p class="preisproliter"><?php 
$flaschenpreis = $product->get_price_html(); 
$literpreis = 0.75; 
$division = $flaschenpreis / $literpreis; 
echo $division; 
?></p>
```

The first line is displayed correctly, but for the second one is displaying only a `0` value.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the <br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to manipulate the price value with calculations, you should use [**`get_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price) instead of [**`get_price_html()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price_html) method.

Your code:

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> / Flasche <br> </p>
<p class="preisproliter"><?php 
$flaschenpreis = $product->get_price(); // <= HERE
$literpreis = 0.75; 
$division = $flaschenpreis / $literpreis; 
echo $division;
?></p>
```

Once your calculations are done and working, you could use optionally **`'woocommerce_price_html'`** filter hook **to format `$division` value** *(as **`get_price_html()`** does)*.

To Optionally display **`$division`** FORMATTED HTML value you could use in your code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_html', $division, $this );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer!

Well, it still didn't work, because I have variable prices. If I Use
$product->get_price() instead of $product->get_price_html(), I get $division = $flaschenpreis * 6 / $literpreis; as a result.

I guess the reason is, that my first variation of the product is price * 6. So

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> / Flasche <br> </p>
<p class="preisproliter"><?php 
$flaschenpreis = $product->get_price(); // <= HERE
$literpreis = 0.75; 
$division = $flaschenpreis / $literpreis / 6; 
echo $division;
?></p>
```

leads me to the right price. That still needs to be formatted (rounded to two decimal positions).

Anyway, I think that this is a dirty solution. Is there a clean method? And why is it not possible to use get_price_html a second time?